# For creating common widgets, which one is best Statless, stateFull or simple function with named params?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, statefulwidget, statelesswidget, dynamic-values

If a widget has the same style all over the project. We make it common so that we can easily use that with a minimal number of lines. But which one should I use to create a common widget.

Let's assume I have a text widget and text form field widget with the same style. Which one should I use?

What if the text widget has a dynamic string?
and
what if the text widget has a simple String?

- Stateless widget / stateful widget  or
- Simple Function with named params

Comment: It purely depends on the usage of the widgets.  Can you explain the purpose of your widgets a bit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to flutter team, `Widgets` are better than `helperMethods`, refer to the video [Widgets vs HelperMethods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo),
`StatelessWidgets` are lighter than `StatefulWidget` so as long as you can use `StatelessWidget` over the `StatefulWidget` pick the `StatelessWidget`, but some widget might not work if it was in a `StatelessWidget` such as the `TextField`
if you try to put a `TextField` inside a `StatelessWidget` it will clear it's value everytime you open the keyboard or a dialog pops up, so
`StatelessWidgets` are the best but sometimes it wont work
`StatefulWidget` are the second bes option
`helperMethods` are good only if you have a widget with a shared style inside a single screen